# Selecting distinct values for multiple columns in Single Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a SQL table called "calculation" that looks like this:

```
id | InsulationMaterialId1 | InsulationMaterialId2| InsulationMaterialId3 | InsulationMaterialId4
-----------------------
1  | 34 | 45 | 34 | 50
2  | 34 | 78 | 35 | 51
3  | 35 | 32 | 34 | 52
4  | 36 | 30 | 34 | 53
5  | 40 | 39 | 34 | 34
6  | 41 | 34 | 34 | 56
7  | 42 | 36 | 34 | 53
```

In these table , we have 4 columns with insulation ids , I want to get unique insulation ids in one single column with ',' separated means Output like this :-

```
 id | InsulationMaterialIds 
-----------------------
1  | 34,45,50
2  | 34,78,35,51
3  | 35,32,34,52
4  | 36,30,34,53
5  | 40,39,34
6  | 41,34,56
7  | 42,36,34,53
```

Comment: You should [normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your table, by making only one column for this `InsulationMaterialId` that contains only one value and make it as a foreign key, instead of having four columns or storing them comma separated.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal you're right about that, you can also query faster without using complicated query's if you will normalize your table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**DDL:**

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
      id INT
    , InsulationMaterialId1 INT
    , InsulationMaterialId2 INT
    , InsulationMaterialId3 INT
    , InsulationMaterialId4 INT
)

INSERT INTO @temp (id, InsulationMaterialId1, InsulationMaterialId2, InsulationMaterialId3, InsulationMaterialId4)
VALUES 
    (1, 34, 45, 34, 50),(2, 34, 78, 35, 51),
    (3, 35, 32, 34, 52),(4, 36, 30, 34, 53),
    (5, 40, 39, 34, 34),(6, 41, 34, 34, 56),(7, 42, 36, 34, 53)
```

**#1: Query with PIVOT**

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id, InsulationMaterialId 
    FROM @temp
    UNPIVOT 
    (
        InsulationMaterialId FOR tt IN (
            InsulationMaterialId1, 
            InsulationMaterialId2, 
            InsulationMaterialId3, 
            InsulationMaterialId4
        )
    ) unpvt
)
SELECT 
    t.id, 
    InsulationMaterialIds = STUFF((
        SELECT DISTINCT ',' + CAST(InsulationMaterialId AS VARCHAR(10))
        FROM cte t2
        WHERE t.id = t2.id
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'), 1, 1, '')     
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT id 
    FROM @temp
) t
```

**#2: Query without PIVOT (faster that #1)**

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    InsulationMaterialIds = STUFF((
        SELECT DISTINCT ',' + CAST(InsulationMaterialId AS VARCHAR(10))
        FROM (
            VALUES 
                (InsulationMaterialId1),
                (InsulationMaterialId2),
                (InsulationMaterialId3),
                (InsulationMaterialId4)
        ) t2(InsulationMaterialId)
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'), 1, 1, '')     
FROM @temp
```

**Output:**

```
id          InsulationMaterialIds
----------- ---------------------
1           34,45,50
2           34,35,51,78
3           32,34,35,52
4           30,34,36,53
5           34,39,40
6           34,41,56
7           34,36,42,53
```